# How can I know what was modified in an Excel file hosted on a SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel

Currently, I have an alert set up so that if someone modifies an Excel file I receive an e-mail. It works fine. However, I can I tell what was modified when I go back to check on the file?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here would be related more to good practices when using files. If you use versioning and the whole check-in/check-out system, then the users will be prompted to specify what changes they made when they check the file back in. Alternatively, you can skim the current version of the excel file and the previous version and try to spot any differences (which is not exactly easy when using a huge excel file).

As a last resort, there's always the "Modified by" field - see who modified the file and ask them in person what changes they made.